# How to make 2 panel body (with possibly different sizes) flip in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I've been trying to make two `panel-body`s inside the same `panel` to flip horizontally. The two `panel-body`s should be one above the other, and whenever I go over the panel, they should rotate 180 degrees.

Currently what's happening is that the two `panel-body`'s are sequentially put inside the panel; so, even if one of the `panel-body`s is hidden, it's space is there.

This is my HTML/Twig template:

```
<div class="row" data-checks-url="/checks" id="uptime-checks-panel">

    {% for check in checks %}

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="{{ 'check_' ~ check.id }}">

        <div class="panel text-center flip">
            <div class="panel-body panel-front">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"> {{ check.name }}</h3>
                </div>

                <i {% if check.status=='up' %} class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-5x thumbs-up" {% else %} class="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-5x thumbs-down" {% endif %} id="{{ check.id ~ '_status'}}">   
                    </i>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a href="{{ check.hostname | external_link }}"> {{ check.hostname }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body panel-back">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">last response in {{ check.lastresponsetime }} millisecs </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">last error {{ check.lasterrortime | pretty_timestamp }} ago</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

and this is the CSS I'm currently using regarding the flipping of the two bodies:

```
.flip {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.flip > .panel-front {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip > .panel-back {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip:hover > .panel-front {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip:hover > .panel-back {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

if I add `position: absolute` to both `.panel-front` and `.panel-back` the result is even worse, i.e. all the grid gets unresponsive... Of course I don't want to set a size to the `panel`, because I need a responsive grid.

This is the visual result:

- Before going over the panel:

[image]

- After going over the panel:

[image]

**Notes**:

1. the transition works well, except that the two bodies are not one above the other (as I said above).
2. the two bodies could be of different sizes
3. I don't want to set a size to the panel because I need a responsive grid
4. What I want to achieve is basically the same effect as the left and top most square in [this example](https://css3playground.com/3d-flip-cards/).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem (at least now the two bodies appear to be one above the other) by modifying the selectors `.flip` and `.flip > .panel-back` to:

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
}

.flip > .panel-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

    background-color: green;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
```